# Group Data according to set of rows

Tags: awk

In the first column there is a values from 5.0 to 12 ( increment of .5 each row) which I call set,  in from of each row there is 5 columns with values.

The purpose is for each set found ( 5.0 to 12.0 ), take the 2 column for all set and add in a single set, and to the same case till end of the file.

So the output will be groups of 4 columns ( 1 column + 3 columns from the 3 sets )

**Input file**

```
5.0     0   0   0 128 128
5.5     3  69  18 128 128
6.0     2  79  12  63  15
6.5    -1  75  11  28  24
7.0     0  73  12  32  27
7.5    -1  73  11  35  21
                         
5.0     0   0   0 128 128
5.5     3  69  18 128 128
6.0     1  79  12  61  18
6.5    -1  75  11  28  25
7.0     0  73  11  31  28
7.5    -2  73   9  32  19

5.0     0   0   0 128 128
5.5     3  69  18 128 128
6.0     1  79  12  51  15
6.5    -2  74  12  26  22
7.0    -1  72  11  25  21
7.5    -1  71  11  28  12
```

**Desired Output**

```
5.0   0   0   0   
5.5   3   3   3   
6.0   2   1   1   
6.5 - 1  -1  -2   
7.0   0   0  -1   
7.5 - 1  -2  -1   
                   
5.0   0   0   0   
5.5  69  69  69   
6.0  79  79  79   
6.5  75  75  74   
7.0  73  73  72   
7.5  73  73  71     
                  
5.0   0  0   0    
5.5  18 18  18    
6.0  12 12  12    
6.5  11 11  12    
7.0  12 11  11    
7.5  11  9  11      
                  
5.0  128  128  128
5.5  128  128  128
6.0   63   61   51
6.5   28   28   26
7.0   32   31   25
7.5   35   32   28
                  
5.0  128  128  128
5.5  128  128  128
6.0   15   18   15
6.5   24   25   22
7.0   27   28   21
7.5   21   19   12
```

I have the solution with pearl but I would like to do same with awk

**here the code I have**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @id;
my %data;
my $set = 0;

while(<>) {
    unless (/^\d/) { ++$set; next }
    my ($id, @fields) = (split)[0..5];
    push @id, $id unless $set;
    for my $f (0..$#{fields}) {
        push @{$data{$id}[$f]}, $fields[$f];
    }
}

for my $t (0..4) {
    for my $i (@id) {
        my $p  = shift @{$data{$i}};
        print join (",", $i, @{$p})."\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Please will be great to get the file in csv format.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using multi-dimensional array in `gnu-awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR == 1 || !NF {++n} n==1{key[++k]=$1} {for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) map[i-1][$1][n] = $i} END {for (j=1; j<=length(map); ++j) {for (i=1; i<=k; ++i) {printf "%s", key[i]; for (p=1; p<=n; ++p) printf "%s%s", OFS, map[j][key[i]][p]; print ""} print ""}}' OFS='\t' file

5.0  0    0    0
5.5  3    3    3
6.0  2    1    1
6.5  -1   -1   -2
7.0  0    0    -1
7.5  -1   -2   -1

5.0  0    0    0
5.5  69   69   69
6.0  79   79   79
6.5  75   75   74
7.0  73   73   72
7.5  73   73   71

5.0  0    0    0
5.5  18   18   18
6.0  12   12   12
6.5  11   11   12
7.0  12   11   11
7.5  11   9    11

5.0  128  128  128
5.5  128  128  128
6.0  63   61   51
6.5  28   28   26
7.0  32   31   25
7.5  35   32   28

5.0  128  128  128
5.5  128  128  128
6.0  15   18   15
6.5  24   25   22
7.0  27   28   21
7.5  21   19   12
```

A more readable form:

```sh
awk -v OFS='\t' '
FNR == 1 || !NF {++n}
n == 1 {key[++k] = $1}
{
   for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i)
      map[i-1][$1][n] = $i
}
END {
   for (j=1; j<=length(map); ++j) {
      for (i=1; i<=k; ++i) {
         printf "%s", key[i]
         for (p=1; p<=n; ++p)
            printf "%s%s", OFS, map[j][key[i]][p]
         print ""
      }
      print ""
   }
}' file
```

Comment: Dear Anubhava for some reason it does not work.

Comment: Check this working online demo: https://ideone.com/Khe0Yf

Comment: Dear Abubhava the original file started in first column with 0.5

Comment: Your modified input in question has first record starting with `5.0`

Comment: ,, the code works fine .. i found the error in mi file